# pass template URL in $compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I have a scenario where I need to pass the template URL path in $compile instead of the template like below.

```
function addSubmenu() {
    scope.subMenuAdded = true;
    scope.subMenuVisible = true;
    scope.menuItemClickHandler = function(menuItem) {
        menuController.itemClickHandler.call(menuController, menuItem);
    };
    $compile('<apt-expandable-menu data-menu="menuItem.children" data-on-menu-item-click="menuItemClickHandler" ng-if="subMenuVisible"></apt-expandable-menu>')(scope, function(cloned){
        element.append(cloned);
    });
}
```

Instead of the actual template in $compile I need to pass the template URL like below.

```
function addSubmenu() {
    scope.subMenuAdded = true;
    scope.subMenuVisible = true;
    scope.menuItemClickHandler = function(menuItem) {
        menuController.itemClickHandler.call(menuController, menuItem);
    };
    $compile('./expandableMenuChildItem.template.html')(scope, function(cloned){
        element.append(cloned);
    });
}
```

and in expandableMenuChildItem.template.html:

```
<apt-expandable-menu data-menu="menuItem.children" data-on-menu-item-click="menuItemClickHandler" ng-if="subMenuVisible"></apt-expandable-menu>
```

but it is throwing me an error:

angular.js:14199 Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ./expandableMenuChildItem.template.html

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [$templateRequest](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateRequest) service. Like so:

```
$templateRequest('nameOfTemplate.html').then(function(template){
    $compile(template)(scope, ..);
});
```